# iOS: Add multiple UIImageViews programmatically in runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios

So, I'm doing a Breakout-clone on the iPhone. All elements except the bricks to hit, are created and working as expected with the NIB-file.

However, if I want to create different levels and run collision detection on the bricks, it seems stupid to add them in Interface Builder. How do I add them to the view in code?

I got an image called "brick.png" that I want to use with an UIImageView. Also, I want to have arrays and / or lists with these so I can build cool levels with pattern in the bricks and all :)

How do I do this in code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Mark is right, I would just add where  the image need to be displayed!

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)] autorelease];
NSString *imgFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"brick" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgFilepath];
[imgView setImage:img];
[img release];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

I tested the code and for me only shows when told the coordinates

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

It's really pretty easy. Here's an example of how you would create and display a UIImageView programatically...

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *imgFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"brick" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgFilePath];
[imgView setImage:img];
[img release];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: You probably want to `autorelease` the image view too :)